# Convert and save MvcHtmlString to Image or PDF

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dom

I am currently working on an application that basically builds an MvcHtmlString by mapping a HtmlTemplate with some data dynamically.

What I want to be able to do is to Convert and save this MvcHtmlString as an Image/ PDF to my local disk.

Here is my function that produces the MvcHtmlString after mapping:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Map(this IDictionary<string, object> row, string htmlTemplate)
    {
        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlTemplate);

        foreach (var key in row.Keys)
        {
            var elements = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body")
                                  .Descendants()
                                  .Where(d => d.Attributes
                                               .Any(a => a.Name == "class" && a.Value == key));
            if (elements != null && elements.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var element in elements)
                {
                    object attributeValue = null;
                    row.TryGetValue(key, out attributeValue);

                    if (element.HasChildNodes)
                    {
                        // We only get the first img element within the element 
                        // as we dont expect there to be more than one <img> tag
                        // within a parent element
                        var imgChildNode = element.Descendants("img").FirstOrDefault();
                        if (imgChildNode != null)
                        {
                            imgChildNode.SetAttributeValue("src", attributeValue.ToString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            element.InnerHtml = string.Empty;
                            element.InnerHtml = attributeValue.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        element.InnerHtml = string.Empty;
                        element.InnerHtml = attributeValue.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var sw = new StringWriter();
        htmlDoc.Save(new StringWriter(sw.GetStringBuilder()));
        var htmlString = MvcHtmlString.Create(sw.ToString());
        return htmlString;
    }
```

And then I am using this function to save an image (But this just renders a black block)

```
private void SaveImageFromHtml(MvcHtmlString html)
    {
        var decodedHtml = html.ToHtmlString();
        Bitmap m_Bitmap = new Bitmap(600, 800);
        PointF point = new PointF(0, 0);
        SizeF maxSize = new System.Drawing.SizeF(600, 800);
        HtmlRenderer.HtmlRender.Render(Graphics.FromImage(m_Bitmap), decodedHtml,
                                                point, maxSize);

        m_Bitmap.Save(@"D:\Test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the reason. The HtmlRenderer library that I was using didnt support "float" in css markup and hence the output image was messed up